# Converting a javascript folder to python

Tags: python, chatbot, twitch

So I know js2py is a thing but I'm not entirely sure if you can convert an entire folder? I only know how to use python and being able to convert the language would be extremely helpful for me, I'm trying to make a twitch chat bot however moderation commands and configuration is difficult for me and the destinygg chat bot is insanely good and being able to use it would be amazing. https://github.com/destinygg/chat-bot
If this is not possible I understand however its worth a shot to ask how/if I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

No, it supports translating a file but not a folder.

But you can [enumerate the files in your folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory) and translate them one-by-one, using:

```
js2py.translate_file('example.js', 'example.py')
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/xTJJP6l.png  Does this mean that its not possible to use js2py to translate the js file? Is there another way to do this or am I screwed?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py/issues/225. As a general rule, translating from one programming language to another is very rarely done and hence the tooling around this is likely to be immature and not bullet-proof. If it's a modest amount of code, it's better to rewrite it natively.

Comment: its not a modest amount of code its an entire folder like I said

Comment: Then find out what the tool's plans are for supporting es6, or rewrite the non-es5.1 parts in es5.1, or use babel to transpile to es5.1 so the tool *does* work.